# Theoretically, what data structure can I use for trees with shared memory?

Tags: .net, algorithm, data-structures, tree

#### Real world problem

I have a forest of trees. Like 20,000 trees. This forest occupies too much memory. But these trees are similar - you could find groups of trees (for ~200 trees) so that they have a common subtree of quite a significant size (tens of %).

#### Theory

So knowing that:

> Trees are similar i.e. they share a common *connected subgraph including the root* (not necessarily including the leaves - but possibly).

Does there exist any data structure that allows for efficient storing of that information? Once the structure is created, **I'm only interested in reading**.

It doesn't necessarily be a solution tight to .NET, I could code it from scratch, I just need the idea :D But of course, if there is some little-known structure in .NET that *kind of* achieves that, I would be pleased to know.

I have a feeling that this shared memory stuff may have something to do with immutable structures that by definition are expected to share memory...

My trees are not binary search trees, unfortunately. They can have any amount of children.

#### Reading

As for reading, it is quite simple. I am always navigating **from the root to a leaf**. As you would in any JSON or XML, given an exact path to a value.

#### Nature of similarity

The *connected subgraph including the root* that is same (potentially) among two trees **always** contains the root and spans down. In some cases it is possible to even reach the leaves. See an example (the yellow part is the *connected subgraph including the root*):

[image]

Given these rules, mathematically speaking all the trees are *similar* - the connected subgraph is either empty, or it contains only the root, or inductively - it contains the root and its children...

Comment: I think the difficulty would be around the "not necessarily including the leaves" part - when you've got a shared structure, it's difficult to break back out into non-shared without having to maintain possibly as much state as you saved by sharing. Also, it may be important to know *how* you'll be reading the trees - what are the inputs and operations you'll be performing (e.g. is it always a specific type of search from the root, or might it be sibling searches from arbitrary nodes, etc?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've just added an edit about the way of querying the trees. I believe it may be a huge simplification - I am never interested in a node other than a leaf. I always seek a single leaf, routing from the root down to the values.

Comment: It would be even possible to store paths to all the values and think of turning a collection of paths into a new tree... Again, it's read-only.

Comment: The "Nature of similarity" section is perfectly opaque to my understanding.

Comment: 1) If these "common" subtrees can lead to different leaves when iterated from two different trees, then each node in that subtree needs to store information on how to branch for each parent tree. 2) How large are these trees? "Occupying too much memory" in server apps might simply mean adding some more RAM. Or switch to b-trees and store the data on a disk, possibly an SSD. Can you provide a small example of two such trees with shared subtrees but different leaves?

Comment: It sounds like you need a Read-only [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). A read-only n-ary tree can be represented as a DAG as common sub-trees can share the same part of the DAG.

Comment: @Enigmativity - unfortunately, it sounds like the common subtrees may be a misnomer here - it appears that it's the root structure that is common, not the leaves.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Damien: well, the only thing DAG provides over trees is a way to have multiple parent nodes for a node, however traversing towards the leaves is OPs problem. But yes, DAG is certainly a structure which will "merge" multiple trees with shared parts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I agree that was an unfortunate name. A better one would be *connected subgraph including the root*, I believe. I've changed it and also added a picture that shows an example of how it looks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - It then sounds like this is a standard tree with different XML-like namespaces.

Comment: @Randolph - I'm not understanding how the diagram relates to the question. I don't understand what the yellow part shows. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group children of your tree node by different "owners". When you add a node, you specify owner (or null to use default "shared" owner). When you traverse your tree, you also specify owner. Here is a sketch code:

```
class TreeNode {
    protected static readonly object SharedOwner = new object();
}

class TreeNode<T> : TreeNode {        
    private readonly T _data;
    private readonly Dictionary<object, List<TreeNode<T>>> _children;

    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this._data = data;
        _children = new Dictionary<object, List<TreeNode<T>>>();
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T data, object owner = null) {
        if (owner == null)
            owner = SharedOwner;
        if (!_children.ContainsKey(owner))
            _children.Add(owner, new List<TreeNode<T>>());
        var added = new TreeNode<T>(data);
        _children[owner].Add(added);
        return added;
    }

    public void Traverse(Action<T> visitor, object owner = null) {
        TraverseRecursive(this, visitor, owner);
    }

    private void TraverseRecursive(TreeNode<T> node, Action<T> visitor, object owner = null) {
        visitor(node._data);
        // first traverse "shared" owner's nodes
        if (node._children.ContainsKey(SharedOwner)) {
            foreach (var sharedNode in node._children[SharedOwner]) {
                TraverseRecursive(sharedNode, visitor, owner);
            }
        }
        // then real owner's nodes
        if (owner != null && owner != SharedOwner && node._children.ContainsKey(owner)) {
            foreach (var localNode in node._children[owner]) {
                TraverseRecursive(localNode, visitor, owner);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a sample usage:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // this is shared part
        var shared = new TreeNode<string>("1");
        var leaf1 = shared.AddChild("1.1").AddChild("1.1.1");
        var leaf2 = shared.AddChild("1.2").AddChild("1.2.1");
        var firstOwner = new object();
        var secondOwner = new object();
        // here we branch first time
        leaf1.AddChild("1.1.1.1", firstOwner);
        leaf2.AddChild("1.2.1.1", firstOwner);
        // and here another branch
        leaf1.AddChild("1.1.1.2", secondOwner);
        leaf2.AddChild("1.2.1.2", secondOwner);
        shared.Traverse(Console.WriteLine, firstOwner);
        shared.Traverse(Console.WriteLine, secondOwner);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}
```

Comment: +1 This looks cool, it's similar to what I've drawn in my answer, but you did the mapping inside each node ("owner" -> child node mapping). If the assumption that OPs "common subtrees" are equal by both structure and content (i.e. that reaching `1.1` inside the shared part is a valid node for multiple graphs), then there might be space savings for these inner nodes which don't need mapping.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind (since OPs initial idea is to conserve space): When it gets full, .NET dictionary will resize the internal buckets array to at least twice the size of previous count (more specifically, next larger prime). For example, if you had 3 items in a dictionary and added a 4th one, it would resize the bucket array to 11. When you take the number of graphs and nodes into account, this might present a noticeable waste in space which might make the whole optimization less effective.

Comment: For a write-once, read-often tree structure, it would also make sense to keep these dictionaries trimmed, or even use a plain array if number of graphs is relatively low.

Comment: @Groo if that indeed would bite OP, he can avoid that by passing initial capacity explicitly in Dictionary constructor (if possible of course, that is if that is known beforehand). Valid concern still.

Comment: That would be better (if possible), although it also uses the next prime larger than the specified capacity. Ultimately it will depend on the ratio of the number of leaves which *need* a dictionary vs number of inner nodes which *don't*. But since you provided an implementation, it's now easy for OP to profile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "reusing" a part of a tree with different leaves is that you need to provide additional information about how to map the leaves of the common part to different graphs. Since your search can end up in any node within the common part, this means you need to map each node in this common subtree to "actual" nodes inside each graphs.

For example, these two "similar" trees A and B share a common part of a subtree (nodes `1`, `3`, `6`, `7`, `8`):

[image: A and B share a common subtree]

To reuse the "common part", you would do something like:

[image: Each tree needs its own lookup table]

Does this provide any space savings? Well, if knowing `A` and `3` means you can directly "calculate" `A3` without a need for  a lookup, then in this particular example, you wouldn't need to map "inner" common nodes `3` and `6` for any of the graphs, saving a bit of space.

In other words, if these common subtrees don't only share their structure, but also their content, then you only need to map exit nodes (leaves) to separate graph nodes.

**(Update)**

For completeness sake, I've added a diagram of [@Evk's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068271/69809), which stores lookup tables inside the actual nodes. Space wise, it shouldn't be different, but since you have a working example in that answer, it might be useful to visualize it:

[image]

Since you know the details of the actual data you're dealing with, you might be able to squeeze a bit of space here and there, but my recommendation would still be to either:

1. Add more RAM to the machine, or
2. Use a disk-based tree, potentially a b-tree, even better if using an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, part of the solution is to have roots of the subtrees shared by several trees, and information in the leaves that tells to which tree a leave belongs. The way to arrange this information depends on the kind of queries you need to perform.

---

With the new explanation, I understand that you need to represent the maximal tree and enhance the nodes with a "stop list" that indicates which among the partial trees stops at this node, i.e. doesn't share more descendants.

Once again, the appropriate data structure for the stop list depends on the access pattern.

It is highly probable that this repesentation be *less* compact than the simple forest of trees.

Comment: I would call this a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @groo: I wouldn't.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I think I would.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried AVL Trees (auto-balancing binary trees) yet? If not, this data structure is efficient in such situations.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a correlation between a forest of similar not-necessarily-binary trees and a self-balancing binary search tree... Could you please give an idea of what approach you have in mind?